# How to printf row where I found largest number in 2d array?

Tags: c

I know how to find largest number, but not how to printf that row?.............................................................................................................................................

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
    int i,j,n, max_i, max_j;
    printf("Input size of a matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int mat[n][n];


    printf("Input numbers in matrix:");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    max_i=0;
    max_j=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(mat[max_i][max_j]>mat[i][j]){
                mat[i][j]=mat[max_i][max_j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Largest number is %d, print of his whole row is %d", mat[max_i][max_j], mat[i][0] ); // I think here is a problem, but who knows
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make a variable for the row and when you find a bigger number, just save `i` in the row variable

Comment: please use english messages in the code which will help others to identify the messages @Zvonimir Brle

Comment: I know i have to do that but I dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a varible to store the max number and the row of the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
int i,j,n, max_number, max_number_row;
printf("Ucitajte velicinu matrice:");
scanf("%d", &n);
int mat[n][n];


printf("Ucitajte brojeve u matricu:");
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}

max_number = mat[0][0];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(mat[i][j] > max_number){
                max_number = mat[i][j];
                max_number_row = i;
            }
    }
}
printf("Najveci broj je %d, a ispis cijelog retka je %d", max_number, max_number_row ); 
return 0;
}
```

Edit 1:

As myxaxa mentioned in the other answer, if you want to print every number of the row you need to make a loop through the max_number_row.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
int i,j,n, max_number, max_number_row;
printf("Ucitajte velicinu matrice:");
scanf("%d", &n);
int mat[n][n];


printf("Ucitajte brojeve u matricu:");
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}

max_number = mat[0][0];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(mat[i][j] > max_number){
                max_number = mat[i][j];
                max_number_row = i;
            }
    }
}
printf("Najveci broj je %d, a ispis cijelog retka je ", max_number); 
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%d ", mat[max_number_row][j]);
} 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it wont printf me that row

Answer (score 1):

You are doing almost right, i.e. you are actually looking for the indices where the largest number is (rather than just getting the value of the largest number).

You just have a mistake in updating the max-indices, because...

```
if(mat[max_i][max_j]>mat[i][j]){
         mat[i][j]=mat[max_i][max_j];  // alters the contents of the matrix
}
```

alters the contents of the matrix instead of updating the indices you search for.

Write

```
if(mat[max_i][max_j] < mat[i][j]){
         max_i = i;
         max_j = j;
}
```

and at the end you should have the indices where the max value resides:

```
printf("maximum value is %d and is located at %d/%d\",mat[max_i][max_j],max_i,max_j);
```

Comment: @user694733: Thanks; If it had not been clear that I'm not native English, at least now it is :-)

Comment: I made mistake, I know how to find max value. But I have to printf that whole row where i found that value

Answer (score 1):

if google translate did it correctly and I understood what do you want - so you need to print it one by one, or collect before in the loop:

```
printf("Najveci broj je %d, a ispis cijelog retka je ", mat[max_i][max_j]);
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%d ", mat[max_i][j]);
}
```